# Replacing Raspberry PI HDMI Port

Tags: hdmi

I broke a few pins in the HDMI connector on my Raspberry Pi. I plan on removing the connector and soldering on a new connector.

Does anyone know the appropriate connector to purchase? It seems like the connectors may vary a bit depending on manufacturer (the HDMI port looks a bit different in pictures of different Raspberry Pis). Because of this I imagine the part is somewhat standard.

I believe I need a SMT female right angle HDMI port, but I am not sure about the exact spacing of the through hole portions of the connector and want to make sure the one I purchase is physically compatible with the Pi's circuit board.

Comment: I searched a little and came up empty handed. I guess the most straight forward option is to de-solder the current connector and do some measurements, with a caliper, on that one and compare those measurements with the available connectors on RS/Element14/Digikey.

Comment: You could dig out whatever schematics there are and see if there's a type code for the connector. Layout images should have a precise footprint, if those are available.

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be cheaper to purchase a new Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It would have been cheaper once I factor in the cost of the new soldering station I bought! But the SMT connector itself is a very cheap part ($1 or so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part is pretty standard.  I'm pretty sure (though admittedly not 100%) that an SMT connector like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/10029449-001RLF/609-1010-1-ND/1002823?WT.mc_id=PLA_1002823&gclid=COL1scuogbQCFUqoPAodNWMA9Q) will work just fine.  There isn't really variation among HDMI connectors, unless you are using them for different mounting positions.

I've looked at the [HDMI module](http://www.andrewscheller.co.uk/rpi_pcb_modules.html) and the [CAD drawing](http://portal.fciconnect.com/Comergent//fci/drawing/10029449.pdf), and the surface contact positions match up.  There are actually no through-hole connections used for the HDMI connector, just 4 SMT solder points (along with the HDMI pin solder points).

Comment: My chip quik just arrived, but the SMT connector is still on order. I appreciate all the help. I will post back in a few weeks once I get a chance to try replacing it.

Answer (score 6):

After the helpful responses from John and ikku I bought a pair of "HDMI Female Jack 19pin Connectors 180 Degree" from ebay. It was just a few dollars.

I also picked up a new temperature controlled soldering Iron and a ChipQuik low temp solder SMT replacement kit.

The instructions for the kit were to cover the connections with flux, apply the low temp solder, and remove the part. I had a bit of trouble because of the four pieces of the HDMI connector that went through the board for structural support. I ended up clipping those, removing the jack, and then removing the four remaining pices.

Afterwards I cleaned the area with alcohol and then soldering the new jack on. The flux that came with the ChipQuik (seems like really nice stuff, but I don't have a lot of experiance with flux) was very helpful in removing the solder bridges accross the 19-pins on the jack. Afterwards I cleaned again with alcohol.

I booted it and it almost worked... the hdmi was fuzzy and dropping in and out. I hit each of the 19-pins once more with my solding iron and new everything seems to be working well.

The takeways:

1. The jack seems like a standard part
2. Good flux was key. I think the low temp solder helped, but I might have been able to do this without it. It certainly didn't hurt so I am glad I bought it.
3. The temperature controlled solding iron made a big difference. Not sure I could have done this with a cheap iron like I've used before.

Thank you for all the help!